# How to search for characters present in a file in python?

Tags: python, file-io, alphabet

I have a file of nearly 1500 lines that contains symbols like ")(()(*&*&^%&^**a**%&#@%^%*&^" alongwith some two or three alphabets in the entire file.

How can i search for these alphabets in such file and display the found alphabets on the o/p screen.

Comment: So if the letters `A`, `B` and `C` are sprinkled through this giant file, you want to output `ABC`?

Comment: yeah or something like a,b,c...

Comment: i mean to say any character like a,b,c .... z can be present in this file and the o/p should display the characters that are present in it like d,e should be the o/p if the file contents are "*)(*)(&(&^&%$^%$#d^&^%&*e*)()"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the fastest way would be to do

```
import re
with open("giantfile.txt") as infile:
    print(re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", infile.read()))
```

Comment: @tobias_k: Perhaps rather read the file in (large) chunks. But yeah, depends on the structure of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Tim's answer, you can use this code to save some memory.

```
import re

alphas = []
with open("giantfile.txt") as infile:
    for row in infile:
        alphas.extend(re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", row))

print alphas
```

Given this input file:

```
aaa
bbb
c12d
```

The output would be

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'c', 'd']
```